# extracting selected button from html5 dataset

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a HTML button with `data-element`, and I am trying to extract the value of the clicked button.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.setAttribute("data-id", article.year + 'q' + i);
    console.log(button); 
    button.className = 'qbutton';
    li.appendChild(button);
}

ul.appendChild(li);

var k = document.querySelector(".qbutton");
k = k.dataset.id
console.log('getElementByClassName k: ', k);
console.log('typeof k: ', typeof(k));
console.log(k);

var selectedButton = document.elementFromPoint(centerX, centerY);
selectedButton= selectedButton.querySelector(".qbutton");
selectedButton= selectedButton.dataset.id;
console.log('selectedButton:', selectedButton);
```

[image]

1. `selectedButton` is always 2006q1, no matter which one I click
2. selectedButton = selectedMonthBlock = selectedMonthblock.dataset.id returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataset' of null

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dataset` object

```
 document.elementFromPoint(centerX, centerY).dataset.id;
```

It works like so, if you have a data attribute like so `data-user-name` you use camelcase
`dataset.userName`

[More info about dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Pedantry: dataset is an object, not a selector. Otherwise, +1.

Comment: @gavgrif selectedButton  is still undefined, as per Richard sugestion.

Comment: @Mitya  selectedButton is still undefined, as per Richard sugestion. Can you help?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to be able to solve this. The key line is `var selectedButton = document.elementFromPoint(centerX, centerY);`, but you don't show how you defne `centerX` or `centerY`, or what HTML they relate to. Somehow, that line is not finding the element you think it should (but your code continues to assume that it is.)

Comment: Just as @Mitya said. Regarding what you tell us, this 'suggestion' is the good answer. Give us more detail of what you are trying to do. Your problem now is that you can't manage to select your element